# Some issue with the webpage display

Tags: html, css

Could anybody kindly tell me why there is a frame shadow when I clicked on the navigation bar? And this only appears on Chrome. It works fine with Safari and Firefox. No idea about IE.

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkWwh.jpg).

Comment: without html and css your questions can not be answered!

Comment: Check if there is some border defined in your CSS code :[fox](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7334327/fox)

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @KamranAhmed Because its happy holidays day and friendly people are welcoming the newcomers with joy to help build the community stronger.

Answer (score 1):

Add this css rule to prevent browsers from adding their own outline and this affects all elements you have in your html.

```
* {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: so may  i ask the reason why you are so sure that its outline and not anything else?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя as you can see on the image there is a browser outline and my understanding to his question I suspect that this might be the outline problem.

Comment: it could be background image or anything!

Comment: Could be, but you gotta start somewhere. His answer is editable. Outline is usually the first thing you look at for that problem. This either solves it or eliminates the first possibility.

Comment: @Dave can you show us the code so that we can help?

Comment: thanks for your sharing! Your suggestion also worked as another one. It seems that both solutions should work together!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, this is due to predefined styles that the browser sometimes sets. To save this from happening in the future, all of your projects should include a CSS normalize - this is a special style sheet that counteracts all of the inherited weirdness from the browser styles.

You can download a copy of normalize here:

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Add it as a separate style sheet in the head of your project, or post it at the very top of your style sheet.

Comment: Many thanks! It works!

Comment: It works together with Yona's suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to the outline property of the a tag. use in your css `outline:0;` or `outline: none;` and this should do the trick.

Comment: yes, you are also right! Thanks!